# Android : How to invoke media player

Tags: android, media-player, sd-card

I have many songs in SD card. All I want to do is, just invoke the default media player. How can I do this??

I found methods to invoke media player and play 1 song but not all the songs in SD card. Also I found a method to play songs in the internal memory not the one in the SD card.

Can someone help me or direct me to some tutorial.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar problem is discussed here:

[Play playlist with MediaPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030487/play-playlist-with-mediaplayer)

Apparently, media player cannot handle playlists. So you should try to listen for completion events using `setOnCompletionListener()` and play next song when such an event happens.

More info:
[Listener (or handler) for video finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847818/android-listener-or-handler-for-video-finish)

Comment: I'll try to follow that method and see. Thanks :)

Comment: it worked for me. May be i should share the code with others in a blog post or something.